# RelaxNG Schema Validation with two choices and interleave

Tags: xml, validation, xml-validation, relaxng

Hi I have a RelaxNG schema like this.

```
<element xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" name="museum">
<interleave>
    <choice> 
        <element name="group1"><empty/></element> 
        <group>
            <interleave> 
                <element name="group1.member1"><empty/></element>
                <element name="group1.member2"><empty/></element> 
            </interleave> 
        </group> 
    </choice> 
    <choice> 
        <element name="group2"><empty/></element> 
        <group> 
            <interleave> 
                <element name="group2.member1"><empty/></element>
                <element name="group2.member2"><empty/></element> 
            </interleave> 
        </group> 
    </choice> 
</interleave>
</element>
```

I am trying to validate the below schema and I am getting error.

> Expecting an element group2.member2, got nothing

I believe it is the interleave error. I would like to interleave group1.member1, group1.member2, group2.member1 and group2.member2 in any order. Please do not provide the answer in Compact RelaxNG. For some reason, I can't use compact one. Any help is appreciated.

```
<museum>
    <group1.member1/>
    <group2.member1/>
    <group1.member2/>
    <group2.member2/> 
</museum>
```

Comment: What are you using for validation? If I run `jing` on your RNG and XML I get an error in the RNG because the top level `element` is not closed. Once I fix that, there's no error.

Comment: I am using lxml for python code. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: If it’s a problem that you can’t reproduce when using jing, then it’s due to one of the number of long-standing known bugs in libxml2’s RelaxNG support that there has never been any action on fixing. The solution is to not use anything that relies on libxml2’s RelaxNG support.